# Ubuntu on DVD, ready to install still boots to windows

Tags: installation

I have burned ubuntu onto a start up dvd as instructed. It is in the DVD drive prior to starting up the computer. When I turn computer on it goes to windows vista. Nothing has changed. How do I install this operating system?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't write your question in all CAPS. That is considered rude and will not help in getting better answers. Your issue is very specific about your hardware. Consult your motherboard/system manual on how to boot from another medium than your internal hard drive. This site is about Ubuntu - your question is mostly off-topic here as it concerns your specific hardware settings.

Comment: Did you simply burn a data DVD with the Ubuntu .iso file on it, or did you recreate the original disk by converting the disk image file (the .iso) back into a true copy of the original disk? If this makes no sense to you, that's one thing you've certainly done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Watch your screen carefully when you press the power button.  There will be a brief screen display where it shows function keys at the bottom right while booting.  It's usually F2 and F12.  Press F12 to enter boot options (If you don't catch this screen you can try again, and keep tapping F12 every 2 seconds right after you press the power button, and that should catch the screen when it gets to it).  Once you are there select to boot from CD, and follow the instructions to install Ubuntu.